# Mount VMWare Disk Images Under Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, disk-image, vmdk

Is it still possible to mount VMWare disk images under Linux?

I found the following two articles, both of them recommend to use `kpartx -av diskimage-flat.vmdk`. However both the articles are old and, when I try it on my Ubuntu Utopic 14.10, it no longer works any more.

```
$ sudo kpartx -av MyWin81.vmdk

$ sudo ls /dev/mapper/loop* | wc -l 
ls: cannot access /dev/mapper/loop*: No such file or directory
0
```

Disclosure: My VMWare disk image IS a flat disk image. Furthermore (before you recommend loop mount), it is a multi-partition disk image, with first partition being Window8 and next two in Linux. It is the next two Linux partitions that I'm more interested to work on.

Can someone confirm please? Thanks.

**Mount Flat VMWare Disk Images Under Linux**
http://cromoteca.com/en/blog/mountflatvmwarediskimagesunderlinux/

**Mount a VMware virtual disk (.vmdk) file on a Linux box**
http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12554/mount-a-vmware-virtual-disk-.vmdk-file-on-a-linux-box

**UPDATE:**

`vmware-mount` looks very promising, but I can't get it working yet:

```
$ vmware-mount -p Win81.vmdk
VixDiskLib: Invalid configuration file parameter. Failed to read configuration file.
Nr      Start       Size Type Id Sytem                   
-- ---------- ---------- ---- -- ------------------------
 1       2048   78643200 BIOS  7 HPFS/NTFS
 2   78645248    6039552 BIOS 83 Linux
 3   84684800   41144320 BIOS 83 Linux

% vmware-mount Win81.vmdk 1 /mnt/tmp1/
VixDiskLib: Invalid configuration file parameter. Failed to read configuration file.
Failed to mount partition 1 of disk 'Win81.vmdk' on '/mnt/tmp1/': Insufficient permissions to perform this operation

% vmware-mount -L
VixDiskLib: Invalid configuration file parameter. Failed to read configuration file.
No mounted disks.

$ vmware-mount | head -3
VixDiskLib: Invalid configuration file parameter. Failed to read configuration file.
VMware DiskMount Utility version 6.0.0, build-2496824

Usage: vmware-mount diskPath [partition num] mountPoint
```

NB, the 2nd and 3rd command is run directly as `root`, yet I get "*Insufficient permissions to perform this operation*"?

Comment: [Confirmed](http://www.cyborgworkshop.org/2014/07/05/mount-a-vmdk-in-linux-without-having-vmware-installed/). Or maybe try _vboxmanage_?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use qemu:

### For `.vdi`

```
sudo modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd1 ./linux_box/VM/image.vdi
```

if they are not installe you can install them (on Ubuntu is this comand)

```
sudo apt install qemu-utils
```

and then mount it

```
mount /dev/nbd1p1 /mnt
```

### For `.vmdk`

```
sudo modprobe nbd
sudo qemu-nbd -r -c /dev/nbd1 ./linux_box/VM/image.vmdk
```

notice tha I use the option `-r` that's because **VMDK version 3 must be read only** to be able to be mounted by qemu

and then I mount it

```
mount /dev/nbd1p1 /mnt
```

I use `nbd1` because `nbd0` sometimes gives 'mount: special device /dev/nbd0p1 does not exist'

### For .ova

```
tar -tf image.ova
tar -xvf image.ova
```

The above will extract the `.vmdk` disk and then mount that.

My configuration:

> ```
> Ubuntu: 16.04.3 LTS 
> Kernel: 4.4.0-112-generic  
> Package: qemu-utils version: 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.22 
> Vmdk: 3 but should be any
> ```

Comment: Thanks Eduard. Please let people know what OS your machine is on, e.g., run `lsb_release -a` and/or `uname -a`, and tell us the version of `qemu`  and `vmdisk` that you are using now, then post back the results.

Comment: works with `qemu-nbd 2.12.0
` on Arch Linux - I had to skip using `-r` for a file on a filesystem mounted `ro`

Answer (score 2):

In my machine the loop devices are in `/dev`. [This article](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12554/mount-a-vmware-virtual-disk-.vmdk-file-on-a-linux-box) mentions /dev/wrapper and /dev, so it could be of help to you.

On the other hand, [this other article](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vddk.utils.doc_50%2Fdiskutils_mount.4.4.html) uses the `vmware-mount` command to accomplish the same.

Note: My system is Slackware64-current (mostly), but with mainly gtk-based software.

Comment: Just another idea: It seems Virtualbox recognizes `vmdk` images. So maybe the remark from sehams on your original question is not as farfetched as it seemed to me. If you install VB, you could possibly use `vboxmanage` to convert, then just `mount` it with `loop` device.

Answer (score 2):

Install affuse, then mount file with it:

```
affuse /path/file.vmdk /mnt/vmdk
```

Check sector size

```
fdisk -l /mnt/vmdk/file.vmdk.raw

# example

Disk file.vmdk.raw: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000da525

Device       Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/mnt/vmdk/file.vmdk.raw1 *     2048 41943039 41940992  20G 83 Linux
```

Multiply sectorsize and startsector. In example it would be 2048*512

```
echo 2048*512 | bc
1048576
```

Mount using that offset

```
mount -o ro,loop,offset=1048576 /mnt/vmdk/file.raw /mnt/vmdisk
```

Disk should now be mounted and readable on /mnt/vmdisk

Comment: How could I made it r/w?

Comment: Thanks MetalGodwin. Please let people know what OS your machine is on, e.g., run `lsb_release -a` and/or `uname -a`, and tell us the version of `affuse` and `vmdisk` that you are using now, then post back the results. Thx.